# Color of hyperlink in web outlook

Tags: html, css, email, hyperlink, outlook

I have got question about colors of hyperlink in html mail.

Iam coding html mails without using images. Only html and css, but i have got problem with hyperlinks. 
Iam using similar html with inline css to make a button.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400"style="background-color:#2C9AB7; border-collapse:separate; border-radius:4px;">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding:15px; text-align:center;">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; display:block; text-decoration:none; width:100%;">Buy Now</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It works prefectly in outlook 2007, but in this outlook https://outlook.office365.com (web outlook) is not hyperlink in white color, but it appears in default blue

I was trying to add some css to header, but it didnt help.

Do you have any sugestions? thx

Comment: I cannot test it, but you should first try to add background color to `td` and `a` element style. So not only `style="color:#FFFFFF;` but ` style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #2C9AB7;`

Answer (score 0):

this solution its works

This button should work with the following email clients:

GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail, and Outlook.com (webmail)
iPhone 3GS, iPhone 5, iPad, Apple Mail
Outlook 2000 through Outlook 2013
Android 2.3 & Android 4.0 mail client
Windows Phone 7
Lotus Notes 8+
BlackBerry 5+
AOL Mail

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr> 
<td align="center" width="300" height="40" bgcolor="#000091" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
<a href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">Awesome Email Button</a>
</td> 
</tr> </table>
```

here is a method

```
<div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:53px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#556270">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://"
style="background-color:#556270;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:53px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Get my free hours now!</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
```

Comment: i tried this example, but it didnt worked for me :(http://imageshack.com/a/img843/6785/im7.gif